# Daphne, twisted pip error when installing django channels

Tags: python, django, python-3.5, django-channels

I have a small problem with `pip` installing `django channels`, I noticed this from the *github* repository

> Note: Recent versions of Channels also need recent versions of Daphne,
>   asgi_redis and asgiref, so make sure you update all at once

I have neglected this and just started with `pip install channels`, but error occurred

`Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement twisted<16.3,>=15.5 (from daphne) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for twisted<16.3,>=15.5 (from daphne)`

and when I try `pip install twisted`, it's just get confusing

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement twisted (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for twisted
```

So I have tried to find some solutions for this, and the solution suggest that I recompile my python, so I'm asking you is there any other solutions for resolving this issue.

I'm using `django==1.8.7` and `python3.5` for my existing project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Channels is entirely new concept and in beta, In this time recommended way to install channels is `pip install -U Channels`

Of cource, you can install twisted by visiting in this page http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ and download the source file and install it.

Comment: Well not exactly I have talked to the creator of `django-channels` and bottom line is that they are going to publish support for `python3.5` in the next `twested 16.4` release in the mean time he suggested me with `pip install https://pypi.python.org/packages/18/85/eb7af503356e933061bf1220033c3a85bad0dbc5035dfd9a97f1e900dfcb/Twisted-16.2.0.tar.bz2#md5=8b35a88d5f1a4bfd762a008968fddab`, and that solved the error I have

Comment: I am trying to install django-channels 1.0.2 and it needs twisted version > 17.1 but due to a Win SDK issue I cannot install it. Furthermore, I cannot install WinSDK on Windows 10 due to some issues that are way over my head. If anyone can tell me of alternate ways to install twisted library, it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mac I think you have to update your `Xcode`.
This worked for me

`xcode-select --install`